# How to get server IP variable in Apache config

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to do an action in Apache 2.4 config based on request matching Server IP (SERVER_ADDR environment variable). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The question seems to broad to get a straight answer, but.. Have you tried "If" or SetEnvIf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetEnvIf` is the answer.

`SetEnvIf Host "^123.*" IPADDR=local
<If reqenv('IPADDR') != 'local'>
  Redirect "/" "https://example.net/"
</If>`